# How to convert the timestamp of Kafka to datetime?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

The following shows a message received. How to convert the timestamp to datetime (python-kafka)?

> ConsumerRecord(topic='topic', partition=0, offset=347, timestamp=1602086275744, timestamp_type=0, key=None, value={......}, headers=[], checksum=3460280057, serialized_key_size=-1, serialized_value_size=471, serialized_header_size=-1).

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.fromtimestamp(1602086275744 / 1000)
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 7, 17, 57, 55, 744000)
```

To keep the precision try this:

```
ms = 1602086275744
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ms//1000).replace(microsecond=ms%1000*1000)
```

Output: `datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 7, 15, 57, 55, 744000)`

If you want to drop the microsecond just do this:

```
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1602086275744 // 1000)
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 7, 15, 57, 55)
```

Comment: Does the timestamp has timezone information? BTW, the two approach still output the same microsecond?

Comment: This has to do with with floating-point division, which is what happens on Python3. To perform integral division, use `//`, because not all platforms support fractional timestamps.